# How can I divide the Action bar of android while adding more than one fragment on Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, material-design

[image: gmail app in tablet mode]

Is there any way to put the search icon aligned with the left fragment(list of email) and others action bar action related to right fragment(detail of selected email)with right. Is there any way (custom or standard) to utilize the status bar for putting icon related to fragment like in gmail app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not status bar, it's ActionBar.
Yes, you can. 
In your Activity, before `setContentView`:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title);
```

So you need to make custom `title` layout and put there everything you want